# Asignar una animación a un div desde javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, web

Estoy intentando esto

```js
function p(){
$('.pr').style.animationName="example";
}
```

```css
.pr{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:black;
}
@keyframes example {
    from {-webkit-transform-origin: 285px 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0) rotate(0deg);}
    to {-webkit-transform-origin: 285px 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate(1285px, 500px) rotate(0deg);}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pr"></div>
<button onclick="p()">haz click</button>
```

Pero no funciona

Que puedo hacer para asignar una animación a un div con javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías agregar una nueva clase en CSS en donde agregas la animación y el tiempo, utilizando el atributo: `-webkit-animation: example 30s;`, luego con Jquery solo le dices que agregue la clase con: `$('.pr').addClass("animation");`:

```js
function p(){
  $('.pr').addClass("animation");
}
```

```css
.pr{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:black;
}
@keyframes example {
    from {-webkit-transform-origin: 285px 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0) rotate(0deg);}
    to {-webkit-transform-origin: 285px 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate(1285px, 500px) rotate(0deg);}
}

.animation {
-webkit-animation: example 30s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pr"></div>
<button onclick="p()">haz click</button>
```